# Trouble Mapping a Geometric Transformations over a List of different types of Graphics Objects

Tags: graphics, animation, map

I am working on some code that allows me to auto-rotate graphics (including ParmetricPlot3D and Plot3D graphics) objects while preserving mouse dragging in a smooth fashion. It works great.

[image]

The code below includes three different types of graphics objects (Graphics3D, ParametricPlot3D, and Plot3D), but I have more types to implement.  I should be able to Map the single geometric transformation over the list but can't figure it out. Independently it works fine and the code is repetitive.  Seems like I should be able to condense but I'm not able.

You can see the repetition three times in the code below.

```
Manipulate[Show[
  
  Map[(GeometricTransformation[#, 
      RotationTransform[Dynamic[\[Theta]], {0, 0, 1}, center]] &), 
   Graphics3D[{Arrow[Tube[{{-3.75, 0, 0}, {3.75, 0, 0}}, .01]], 
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, -3.75, 0}, {0, 3.75, 0}}, .01]], 
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, -3.75}, {0, 0, 3.75}}, .01]]}]],
  
  Map[GeometricTransformation[#, 
     RotationTransform[Dynamic[\[Theta]], {0, 0, 1}, center]] &, 
   ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, v^2}, {u, -4, 4}, {v, -4, 4}]],
  
  Map[GeometricTransformation[#, 
     RotationTransform[Dynamic[\[Theta]], {0, 0, 1}, center]] &, 
   Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]],
  
  PlotRange -> 4, SphericalRegion -> True], {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi, 
  ControlType -> Animator, AnimationRate -> .03}, 
 Initialization :> {center = 
    Mean /@ (PlotRange /. 
       AbsoluteOptions[
        Graphics3D[{Arrow[Tube[{{-3.75, 0, 0}, {3.75, 0, 0}}, .01]], 
          Arrow[Tube[{{0, -3.75, 0}, {0, 3.75, 0}}, .01]], 
          Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, -3.75}, {0, 0, 3.75}}, .01]]}], 
        PlotRange])}]
```

As you can see I have mapped the GeometricTransformation over Graphics3D and ParametricPlot3D and Plot3D independently which I believe is overkill. I have more types to plot as well.  I would like to call the Map function only once for all graphics objects.

I tried using Map to push through the list of graphics objects it doesn't seem to work.  I've also tried, MapThread, MapApply, Apply, etc.

It's probably a very simple solution, but it escapes me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gr = {Graphics3D[{Arrow[Tube[{{-3.75, 0, 0}, {3.75, 0, 0}}, .01]], 
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, -3.75, 0}, {0, 3.75, 0}}, .01]], 
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, -3.75}, {0, 0, 3.75}}, .01]]}], 
   Graphics3D[{Cube[{1, 0, 0}, 1]}], 
   Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}], 
   ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, v^2}, {u, -4, 4}, {v, -4, 4}]};

Manipulate[
 Show[(g |-> 
     Map[(GeometricTransformation[#, 
         RotationTransform[Dynamic[\[Theta]], {0, 0, 1}, center]] &), 
      g]) /@ gr, PlotRange -> 4, SphericalRegion -> True], {\[Theta], 
  0, 2 Pi, ControlType -> Animator, AnimationRate -> .03}, 
 Initialization :> {center = 
     Mean /@ (PlotRange /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[
         Graphics3D[{Arrow[Tube[{{-3.75, 0, 0}, {3.75, 0, 0}}, .01]], 
           Arrow[Tube[{{0, -3.75, 0}, {0, 3.75, 0}}, .01]], 
           Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, -3.75}, {0, 0, 3.75}}, .01]]}], 
         PlotRange]);}]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm sorry I should have been more clear.  My issue is that I have a number of different graphics objects, like Plot3D, and ParametricPlot3D (not all Graphics3D)   I can't figure out how to combine them into your gr variable.  I'll update the question to pinpoint my issue.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: hmmmm.  I am missing something.  : ( Where can include a Plot3D, ParmetricPlot3D, RevolutionPlot3D, etc?  I see how you are combining Graphics3D objects.  But not sure how to incorporate the 3D graphics functions mentioned. Show[] doesn't work.   I've only been able to map the transformations of these functions on an individual basis, yet the code is the same for all of them.  Seems like I should be able to condense the code.  You can see the repetition in my updated post.

Comment: Did you test my last update?

Comment: I did not know you can do that.  Enlightening!  TY